# Trying to study Android Development, but I don't know Java

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, sdk

I've been studying Android Development for the past week or so. The xml stuff is pretty easy to understand. However, I have NO knowledge of java. Whenever the documentation says to do callbacks to the .java file and use oncreate() I get confused and see nothing but errors. Is there an easy way to understand the java stuff? I'm very motivated to learn android development and make applications, only thing holding me back is java.

Comment: Can anyone recommend any introductory java books to aid me in android development?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy way to understand the java stuff?

That kind of depends on where you are coming from.  If you are already experienced in programming in a high-level OO programming language, then the concepts used in Java are not that different.  If you are familiar with C#, C++ or even Javascript or C, you will similarities between language syntaxes.  For simple stuff, you can probably just "wing it", but for more complex stuff, you'll need to dive into a good text book and/or a tutorial.

On the other hand, if you are not an OO programmer (or not a programmer at all) then you've got a lot of work to do to learn OO programming / design in general and Java in particular.

In a previous life, I used to teach an "Introduction to Java" course targeted at software developers converting from some other programming language.  It was a 1 week full-time course.  At the end, students would understand the language, and have basic knowledge of some of the fundamental class libraries ... but still only have "beginner level" skills.

So the answer to "is there an easy way" ... not really.

Comment: I have no history of coding at all. I know nothing about C++ or Java. Are there any good documentation online or books I can read? Would a "Java for Dummies" book do me any good?

Comment: OK.  A good introductory Java programming text book would be good, and the willingness and patience to do all of the exercises.  It will probably take a month or so to get to the point where you can write Java code that does something non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks! Any recommendations? I'm going to start with the Java tutorials on Oracle, but I may need more than that.

Comment: I cannot recommend any particular introductory Java text books.  Go to your local bookstore and browse the IT section.

Comment: Will do. Would any Java introductory book do suffice? Or do I need a special edition for android development?

Comment: Either, but make sure that you get a book that doesn't assume that you can already program in some other language.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [informations in the "java" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info).

The best way to start with java is using the [getting started tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) and the complete [tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) collection from oracle.com

Answer (score 0):

Are there any languages you do know? You may be able to find a "Java for .. programmers" to help you get started. For example, if you know Python, ["Java for Python programmers" may help](http://knuth.luther.edu/~bmiller/JavaForPython.html).

There is an [new O'Reilly book on android](http://programming-android.labs.oreilly.com/) planned and it's readable during development. It has a good [Java introduction](http://programming-android.labs.oreilly.com/ch02.html) section.

Lastly, there are frameworks that claim you can develop Android applications using javascript / html / css. It may not be ideal but it may get you started. I have no experience yet with these frameworks. An example is [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/).

Comment: I don't know any languages. I want to just learn Android development and the java that comes with it. How does Python relate to android?

Comment: It doesn't. I have a strong python background (but used to be a java programmer 10 years ago), so it helps me to refresh my knowledge. You basically want to learn three things at once: Android, java and programming in general. You really should start with a basic introductory tutorial.

Comment: I'm going to read the java introduction piece you provided. I'm guessing that won't be enough though. Can you recommend any books?

Comment: I just did some looking on the java website and theres a book called "The Java Tutorial: A Short Course on the Basics, 4th Edition" that is supposedly a great introduction to java. Will these java concepts relate to what I'm seeing in android? Will any java introductory book do suffice, or will I need a special java for android book?